# How to check how many symbols an expression has?

Tags: python, sympy

Do you know how I can check the amount of symbols that an expression has, so I can only save the ones with 3 symbols or less?
Like `a + b + c` is what I want to keep but `a + b + c + d` not.

I have no clue where to even start with solving this problem.

The problem illustrated below: The bottom table contains many expressions that are too large and of no interest which I want to filter out.

Linear combination of equations in the upper table presented in the bottom table:
[image: Linear combination of equations in the upper table presented in the bottom table]

Comment: can you share the code so i can see what kind of variables they are?

Comment: Please avoid posting images (or worse, links to images) of code or errors. Anything text-based (code and errors) should be posted as text directly in the question itself and formatted properly as a [mre]. You can get more [formatting help here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). You can also read about [why you shouldn't post images/links of code](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

Answer (score 2):

This might be an overkill, but you can use python's own tokenizer to tokenize the expression and then filter on the tokens. https://docs.python.org/3/library/tokenize.html

Comment: This could work too, but SymPy's inbuilt function that I found by luck solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out, all I needed has the .has() function and an array with my symbols, in this case it's sym2.

Here you can see the code I implemented.

```py
plus = []
minus = []
#counters 
cp = 0
cm = 0
for eq1 in mlistes[0:, 1]:
    for eq2 in mlistes[0:, 3]:
        tempp = eq1 + eq2
        tempm = eq1 - eq2
        for i in range(0, 8):
            for check in sym2[i]:
                if tempp.has(check):
                    cp = cp + 1
                if tempm.has(check):
                    cm = cm + 1
        if (cp <= 3) and (tempp != 0): 
            plus.append(tempp)
        if (cm <= 3) and (tempp != 0):
            minus.append(tempm)
        cp = 0
        cm = 0
```